# Meaning of type Set = Int => Boolean in Scala

Tags: scala

I do not understand why `Set` defined in this way produces these results.

My understanding is that `Set` is just a function which takes an int and return boolean.

Can someone explain me why I get this result using set?

I think this is a short way to express the function in Scala but I am new to this language and I do not understand how it works.

```
object sets {
  type Set = Int => Boolean

    var a=Set(3)                              //> a  : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(3)
    a(2)                                      //> res0: Boolean = false
    a(3)                                      //> res1: Boolean = true
    a(1)                                      //> res2: Boolean = false
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The type you defined in `type Set = Int => Boolean` and the object you created in `var a=Set(3)` are actually **not connected to each other**. Even this works:

```
scala> type Set = String
defined type alias Set

scala> val a = Set(3)
a: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(3)
```

When you call `Set(3)`, you call `apply` method on the [**object** `Set`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Set%24). If you add `new` keyword, it will take your type alias into account:

```
scala> val b = new Set()
b: String = ""
```

`a(2)`, `a(3)`, `a(1)` work because `Set[A]`, actually, does implement `A => Boolean` function trait and `apply` method is equivalent to `contains`: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Set

Comment: So are you saying that I am just using the Set implemented inside the Scala languages and nothing else? So the initial line is totally useless in my code?

Comment: Yes, you are using Scala's built-in implementation of `immutable.Set`. The type alias doesn't have any effect in the code you provided.

Answer (score 3):

I agree what izstas said they are different things. But "type Set = Int => Boolean" has effect. In the following steps in scala console, after "type Set = Int => Boolean" the error disappears.

```
scala> def func(s:Set) = 1
<console>:10: error: type Set takes type parameters
       def func(s:Set) = 1
                  ^

scala> def func(s:Set[Int]) = 1
func: (s: Set[Int])Int                      <---- specify the type in the set

scala> type Set = Int => Boolean             
defined type alias Set

scala> def func(s:Set) = 1                   <---- no error
func: (s: Set)Int

scala> def getSet(s:Set) = s
getSet: (s: Set)Set

scala> getSet(Set(1,2))
res0: Set = Set(1, 2)

scala> Set(1,2)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2)

scala> val t=Set(1,2)
t: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2)
```

Comment: "type Set = Int => Boolean" actually is a way to define the abstraction of a Set (a function that has the ability to tell the element is in the set or not).

Comment: Thanks @hosais you have resolved my doubts. But if I want to change the type abstraction Set to String instance of Int. Should I use the "type Set =String =>Boolean" or just specifying Set[String] is enough?